# How can I display a single object from an embedded array of objects from Mongodb into a Nextjs application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, next.js

So i am facing a problem. I have an embedded array which is as follows which includes a store and two products in it:

```
{
      restaurantName: 'Rolex Papa',
      restaurantSlug: 'rolex-papa',
      restaurantLogo: '/images/rolexpapa.jpg',
      products: [
        {
          name: 'Rolex2',
          slug: 'rolex2',
          category: 'rolex',
          image: '/images/pork2.jpg',
          price: 2000,
          brand: 'Papa',
          rating: 4.5,
          numReviews: 8,
          countInStock: 22,
          description: 'A very nice and popular product',
          extraOptions: [
            {
              text: 'Tomatoes',
              price: 20,
            },
            {
              text: 'Soda',
              price: 30,
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          name: 'Rolex1',
          slug: 'rolex1',
          category: 'rolex',
          image: '/images/pork1.jpg',
          price: 6000,
          brand: 'Nike',
          rating: 4.5,
          numReviews: 8,
          countInStock: 22,
          description: 'A very nice and popular product',
          extraOptions: [
            {
              text: 'Tomatoes',
              price: 20,
            },
            {
              text: 'Soda',
              price: 30,
            },
          ],
        },
       
      ],
    },
```

I have managed to create a single store page and all seems to be working well. I can fetch all the products in the store and then also all the necessary store information in the [restaurantSlug].js page. see below:

```
import React from 'react';
import Restaurant from '../../models/Restaurant';
import db from '../../utils/db';
import Layout from '../../components/Layout';
import Banner from '../../components/Banner';
import ProductItem from '../../components/ProductItem';
import { useContext } from 'react';
import { Store } from '../../utils/Store';
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';

const RestaurantScreen = (props) => {
  const { restaurant } = props;

  const { state, dispatch } = useContext(Store);
  const { cart } = state;

  const addToCartHandler = async (product) => {
    const existItem = cart.cartItems.find((x) => x.slug === product.slug);
    const quantity = existItem ? existItem.quantity + 1 : 1;

    dispatch({ type: 'CART_ADD_ITEM', payload: { ...product, quantity } });

    toast.success('Product added to the cart');
  };

  return (
    <Layout title={restaurant.restaurantName}>
      <div>
        <div className="container p-2 mx-auto">
          <div className="flex flex-row flex-wrap">
            <div className="hidden md:block sm:w-2/3 md:w-2.8/4 pt-1 px-2 border-gray-200 shadow-md border-2 m-1 rounded-md">
              <Banner />
            </div>

            <div class="ml-7 shadow-lg rounded-2xl w-80 bg-white dark:bg-gray-800">
              <img
                alt="profil"
                src={restaurant.restaurantLogo}
                className="rounded-t-lg h-[150px] md:h-[230px] w-full mb-4"
              />
              <div class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center p-4 -mt-16">
                <a href="#" class="md:hidden block relative">
                  <img
                    alt="profil"
                    src={restaurant.restaurantLogo}
                    class="mx-auto object-cover rounded-full h-16 w-16  border-2 border-white dark:border-gray-800"
                  />
                </a>
                <p class="relative text-gray-800 dark:text-white text-xl font-medium mt-9">
                  {restaurant.restaurantName}
                </p>

                <div class="rounded-lg p-2 w-full mt-2"></div>
              </div>
              <div className="flex justify-around pb-2">
                <p className="py-2 px-4 text-sm font-medium text-center text-white bg-blue-700 rounded-lg hover:bg-blue-900 focus:ring-4 focus:ring-blue-300 dark:bg-purple-600 dark:hover:bg-purple-700 dark:focus:ring-purple-800 mr-4">
                  Contact Us
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="grid grid-cols-1 gap-4 md:grid-cols-3 lg:grid-cols-4">
          {restaurant.products.map((product) => (
            <div>
              <ProductItem
                product={product}
                key={product.slug}
                addToCartHandler={addToCartHandler}
              />
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default RestaurantScreen;

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const { params } = context;
  const { restaurantSlug } = params;

  await db.connect();
  const restaurant = await Restaurant.findOne({ restaurantSlug }).lean();
  await db.disconnect();
  return {
    props: {
      restaurant: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(restaurant)),
    },
  };
}
```

At this point the product is displaying properly while in the store(restaurant screen). But the issue bothered by is why isn't the product not available when i get to the single product page. Here is the code for the single product page i.e.

/product/[slug].js.

```
    import Image from 'next/image';
import Link from 'next/link';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import Layout from '../../components/Layout';
import db from '../../utils/db';
import { Store } from '../../utils/Store';
import Restaurant from '../../models/Restaurant';

export default function ProductScreen({ product }) {
  const { state, dispatch } = useContext(Store);

  const router = useRouter();

  if (!product) {
    return <Layout title="Product Not Found">Product Not Found</Layout>;
  }

  return (
    <Layout title={product.name}>
      <div className="py-2">
        <Link href="/">Back to Products</Link>
      </div>
      <div className="grid md:grid-cols-4 md:gap-3">
        <div className="md:col-span-2">
          <Image
            src={product.image}
            alt={product.name}
            width={640}
            height={640}
            layout="responsive"
          ></Image>
        </div>
        <div>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <h1 className="text-lg">{product.name}</h1>
            </li>
            <li>Category: {product.category}</li>
            <li>Brand: {product.brand}</li>
            <li>
              {product.rating} of {product.numReviews} reviews
            </li>
            <li>Description: {product.description}</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div className="card p-5">
            <div className="mb-2 flex justify-between">
              <div>Price</div>
              <div>${product.price}</div>
            </div>
            <div className="mb-2 flex justify-between">
              <div>Status</div>
              <div>
                {product.countInStock > 0 ? 'In Stock' : 'Out of Stock'}
              </div>
            </div>
            <button
              className="primary-button w-full"
              onClick={addToCartHandler}
            >
              Add To Cart
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Layout>
  );
}

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const { params } = context;
  const { products } = params;

  await db.connect();
  const product = await Restaurant.findOne({ products }).lean();

  return {
    props: {
      product: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(product)),
    },
  };
}
```

I am using mongodb with nextjs for this. Please see the model for the Restaurant:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const restaurantSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  restaurantName: { type: String, required: true },
  restaurantSlug: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  restaurantLogo: { type: String, required: true },
  products: [
    {
      name: { type: String, required: true },
      slug: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
      category: { type: String, required: true },
      image: { type: String, required: true },
      price: { type: Number, required: true },
      brand: { type: String, required: true },
      rating: { type: Number, required: true, default: 0 },
      numReviews: { type: Number, required: true, default: 0 },
      countInStock: { type: Number, required: true, default: 0 },
      description: { type: String, required: true },
      extraOptions: {
        type: [
          {
            text: { type: String, required: true },
            price: { type: Number, required: true },
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  ],
});

const Restaurant =
  mongoose.models.Restaurant || mongoose.model('Restaurant', restaurantSchema);
export default Restaurant;
```

Any help for this will be highly appreciated. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you mixed up the slugs. Also you don't have to JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(...)) the data. You have to use $elemMatch ([docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/)). Try using this:

```
export async function getServerSideProps({ params }) {
  await db.connect();
  const product = await Restaurant.findOne({ restaurantSlug: params.restaurantSlug, products: {
    $elemMatch: {
      slug: params.slug
    }
} });

  return {
    props: {
      product
    },
  };
}
```